# Redux reducer return previous state dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a Redux Reducer that needs to store the previously selected option each time a user selects a new option.

- User Selects A (returns empty array)
- User Selects B (returns A)
- User Selects C (returns B)
- User Selects D (returns C)

.

```
export default function reducer(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case previousSelectionAction.PREVIOUS_SELECTION: {

      // Need to return the previous selection
      // Have tried:
      //  return [...state] and other variations with action.payload and dropping item in array
      // but this just returns the same state, does not update each tie a user selects a new option

    }
default:
  return state;
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making your state a single object, it can be 2 objects one storing the previous value and one storing the current value.

The logic will be something like the following:

```
initialState = { previous: {}, current: {}}

Case updateSelection: 
      return {
        ...state, 
        previous: state.current, 
        current: action.payload
      }
```

Then, you could check state.previous in your code.

Comment: It's pretty clear you just copied my answer and added some fluff.

Answer (score 1):

Store the previous value in a different state property when the selection changes:

```
case updateSelection:
  return {
    ...state,
    previous: state.current,
    current: action.payload
  }
```

And then you can select that previous value.